# Protocol buffer split oneof message to a different file

Tags: protocol-buffers, nanopb

I use nanopb and a .proto file that looks like this (simplified):

```
syntax = "proto3";

message Type1
{
    bool a = 1;
}

message Type2
{
    int32 b = 1;
}

message Message
{
    int32 id = 1;
    oneof oneMessage {
        Type1 messageType1 = 2;
        Type2 messageType2 = 3;
    }
}
```

I now need to split the `oneMessage` to a different .proto file and import it. I can do something like:
file a.proto:

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "b.proto"
message Message
{
    int32 id = 1;
    oneofTypeMessage aMessage = 2;
}
```

file b.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

message Type1
{
    bool a = 1;
}

message Type2
{
    int32 b = 1;
}

message oneofTypeMessage
{
    oneof oneMessage {
        Type1 messageType1 = 2;
        Type2 messageType2 = 3;
    }
}
```

But this means I can't get to my message types with `message.messageType1`, triggering lots of changes in the existing source code. How can I split the oneof part to another file without changing the way I access to it?
I've tried declaring `Message` in both files but it is not permitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `oneMessage` is *not a message type*, and to import something from another file, it must be a message type. Adding a new `oneofTypeMessage` would add an additional node in the graph, and would not be data-compatible with the original data.

You can move `Type1` and `Type2`, but the `oneof` must stay as-was; so: this is valid:

file `a.proto`:

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "b.proto"
message Message
{
    int32 id = 1;
    oneof oneMessage {
        Type1 messageType1 = 2;
        Type2 messageType2 = 3;
    }
}
```

file `b.proto`:

```
syntax = "proto3";

message Type1
{
    bool a = 1;
}

message Type2
{
    int32 b = 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping for a.proto to not need to know about Type1 and Type2 so I can share a.proto with different projects using different b.proto. It is useful to know that it's not possible to do it the way I wanted.